# How do I get the file path of python script within loaded module?

Tags: python, module

I wrote a module `module.py` that I import in various scripts. The module has a function that needs the file path of the script `main.py` that it was imported by and do something with it. How do I get this file path?

```
module.py

def main_file_path():
    print(way_to_acces_main_file_path)
```

is imported in

```
main.py

import module
module.main_file_path()
```

Running main.py should print the file path of main.py

Comment: Why not just pass in a path into `main_file_path`? This will also make it more reusable and generalized.

Comment: Because the real function in `module.py` always needs the file path of the script that imports it, and this function already has a few parameters. I think adding the file path as parameter will complicate the function. I am looking for something like __file__ that I can call in the module.

Comment: This is an odd request. Are you sure there isn't a better way to do what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system `argv` always has the program name as the first element. This should work most of the time:

```py
import sys
import os

path = os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0])
print(path)
```

Comment: This works perfectly for what I intended. I wasn't aware that `sys.argv[0]` also gives the script name that is being executed when called inside a module. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `os` module to get the path of a file:

```py
# file_locator.py

import os


def get_file_location(filename):
    return os.path.abspath(filename)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pass
```

```
# main.py

from file_locator import get_file_location

fileA = get_file_location(filename)
```

Comment: This would work if I only import `module.py` in `main.py`, but I use it in other scripts and want it to be flexible in regards to which script it is imported by.

Comment: I updated the code. Does this offer the flexibility you are trying to achieve?